# Solve for Y in classic bond formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, estimation

I'm trying to set up an excel spreadsheet that solves for $Y$ in the classic bond formula:

$P = \frac{C}{(1+Y)}+\frac{C}{(1+Y)^2}+\frac{C}{(1+Y)^3}+_{......}+\frac{(C + Q)}{(1+Y)^n}$

Where "C" is a constant cash flow, "P" is the present value, and "Q" is a constant par value.  "Y" represents the bond yield.

$n$ will be given, but it will be different each time I input the formula.

I can't solve the algebra.  I don't want to use the Solver function, because the spreadsheet needs to be flexible.  I need to find an equation that either solves for "Y," or estimates it relatively closely.

Can you help?

$Y = _{....}$?

Comment: I changed to writing to make terms simpler without changing the results. Just compute first $(a_0,a_1,b)$ (formulae in blue) and then $Y$ (formula in red). Notice that if we start writing $Q=kC$ the formulae simplify quite nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an *approximation*, let $x=\frac 1 {1+Y}$ making the equation to be
$$P=C\frac{ x \left(x^n-1\right)}{x-1}+Q x^n$$Now, expand the rhs as a Taylor series built at $x=1$ to get
$$P=(C n+Q)+\frac{1}{2} n (x-1) (C (n+1)+2 Q)+\frac{1}{6} (n-1) n (C (n+1)+3
   Q)(x-1)^2 +\frac{1}{24} (n-2) (n-1) n  (C (n+1)+4 Q)(x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ Now, use series reversion to get things like
$$x=1+z-\frac{ (n-1) (C (n+1)+3 Q)}{3 (C (n+1)+2 Q)}z^2+O\left(z^3\right)$$ where $$z=\frac{2 (P-Q-C n)}{n (C( n+1)+2 Q)}$$

Let us try with $P=1500$, $C=100$, $Q=1000$ and $n=20$. This would give
$$z=-\frac{3}{82}\implies x=\frac{262691}{275684}\implies Y=\frac{12993}{262691}\approx 0.049$$

Now, use Newton method using this value as $Y_0$. The iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & Y_n \\
 0 & 0.049461154 \\
 1 & 0.056876669 \\
 2 & 0.057341522 \\
 3 & 0.057343198
\end{array}
\right)$$

You could even do better, considering the equation to be
$$P=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac C {(1+Y)^k}+\frac{C+Q}{(1+Y)^n}$$ Build for the rhs the simplest Padé approximant at $Y=0$  which will be
$$P=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac C {(1+Y)^k}+\frac{C+Q}{(1+Y)^n}\simeq\frac{a_0-a_1 Y }{1+b Y }$$ where
$$\color{blue}{a_0=Cn+Q \qquad a_1=\frac{(n-1) \left(C^2 n (n+1)+4 C (n+1) Q+6 Q^2\right)}{6 (C (n+1)+2 Q)}}$$ $$\color{blue}{ b= \frac{(n+1) (C (n+2)+3 Q)}{3 (C (n+1)+2 Q)}}$$
and solve the resulting equation for $Y$. This would give
$$\color{red}{Y=\frac{a_0-P}{a_1+b P}}$$ Applied to the worked example, this would give $Y=\frac{123}{2270}\approx 0.054185$. Using this starting value, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & Y_n \\
 0 & 0.054185022 \\
 1 & 0.057267092 \\
 2 & 0.057343153 \\
 3 & 0.057343198
\end{array}
\right)$$ As you can see, one single iteration is almost sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that has no direct solution.  Could you use the internal IRR function?  It solves iteratively, but is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative formulas for yield-to-maturity can be looked-up.

Or here is an example of my own development for approximate bond pricing:

Par is 100, annual coupon is $6.17, yield is 4.379%, and redemption is Jan 25 2037.

x = net gain including dividends

y = bond price

x / y = 4.379 * 18 / 100

x = 0.78822y

x + y = (6.17 * 18) + 100

1.78822y = 211.06

y = 118.03

then the inverse

x / 118.03 = r * 18 / 100

x = 21.2454r

21.2454r + 118.03 = (6.17 * 18) + 100

21.2454r = 93.03

r = 4.379% .